# Getting the next textbox using the next() function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write some Jquery code that will get the value of the next textbox that is of a class "in". The code I have here isn't working, the value is always undefined. I think I am using the next() function incorrectly but I am not sure, does anybody have any input?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<input type="text" class="mm" />
<br>
<input type="text" class="in" />  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").focus(function() {

        var value = $(this).next(".in").val();
        if (value) {
            alert(value);
        }

    });
});   

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see the corresponding HTML markup to know whether what you're doing is correct or what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example as you've given the HTML actually works.  You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RGsDq/.  Based on your comments, it sounds like you want the first sibling that has the class "in" whether it's the next sibling or not.  .next() only examines the very next sibling.  If you want the first sibling that has the class "in" even if it's not the very next sibling, you can do either of these:

```
$(this).nextAll(".in").first().val();           // next sibling with class ".in"
$(this).parent().find(".in").first().val();     // next child of parent with class ".in"
```

You can see the first of these two options working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4VwAN/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to post your html. The Next gets the next sibling, so it very much depends on the html structure - it might just need you to add a parent in to get to the point which is a parent of all the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next(".in")` will only return a value if the next element has a class of "in", rather than looking at all siblings for the first textbox with a class of "in". 
Try `$(this).nextAll(".in:eq(0)")`.

Comment: I need it to only look for the first next class with the element of class "in"

Comment: I believe that's what the `:eq(0)` selector does.